# SpringBoot Rest API with failover fallback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, failover

I am building rest API in `springboot`, where my application receive list of data in a request and update the records in DB. I have new requirement where i need to check if any exception thrown by DataBase like Database is down then i need to save the requested data and apply reattempt once Database is up.

To achieve this requirement I am using the `ActiveMQ` where when Database throw any exception then put the requested data in `queue` and once data base is UP then read the queue and insert the data again in DB.

Is there any other way in `springboot` where i can use something else instead of using `ActiveMQ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some approaches you can take on this. First of all, I would recommend you to take a look at [spring-retry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry). It is able to retry operations that failed due to some momentary problem. you can configure it with a number of retries and a delay between the retries.